# How to write an expression for two different attributes in the same field in qlikview

Tags: qlikview, conditional-expressions

Please help me write the script for the following statement in qlikview which I have it in SQL.

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN Total_A=0 THEN 0
           ELSE cast(((Total_B+Total_C)/Total_A) AS decimal (5,2))
       END AS ratio
```

I have Total_A , Total_B and Total_C in the same field called Total_val

Comment: Can you give example of Total_val?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL CASE is usually replaceable by the QlikView if().

Try this

```
 if(Total_A=0,0,(Total_B+Total_C)/Total_A) as Ratio
```

if the A,B,C switch is inside the Val column then it will get a lot more tricky as you will have to aggregate and use nested ifs. But I believe the statement I wrote is equivalent to the SQL you gave us. If my answer doesn't work please give us a few rows of data to look at